# Creating a graph with nx.from_pandas_edgelist

Tags: pandas, networkx, python-3.7

I am writing a function that returns the graph of the articles that either cite or are cited by the article (input DOI), where the DOIs are used to name the articles in the graph and a direct edge from DOI_1 to DOI_2 is added if there exists a citation from DOI_1 to DOI_2.

The CSV citation data is shown as follows:

```
oci,citing,cited,creation,timespan,journal_sc,author_sc
0200100000236252421370109080537010700020300040001-020010000073609070863016304060103630305070563074902,"10.1002/pol.1985.170230401","10.1007/978-1-4613-3575-7_2",1985-04,P2Y,no,no
```

This function creates the df:

```
def do_process_citation_data(f_path):
     global my_ocan

     my_ocan = pd.read_csv(f_path, names=['oci', 'citing', 'cited', 'creation', 'timespan', 'journal_sc', 'author_sc'], parse_dates = ['creation', 'timespan'])
     my_ocan = my_ocan.iloc[1:]  # to remove the first row
     my_ocan['creation'] = pd.to_datetime(my_ocan['creation'], format="%Y-%m-%d", yearfirst=True)
     # Period parsing on my_ocan['timespan']
     print(my_ocan.info())

     return my_ocan
```

When I run this function that creates the graph (print(my_ocan.get_citation_graph('10.1002/pol.1985.170230401')) I get nothing.

```
def do_get_citation_graph(data, doi):
    G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(my_ocan, 'citing', 'cited', create_using=nx.DiGraph())

    return G
```

What's my missing point?

Thank you

Comment: can you include the actual implementation of `do_get_citation_graph`? it's always better to provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hi, @Yuca I edited my question above and added info on how my CSV looks like as well the example that I am running: (print(my_ocan.get_citation_graph('10.1002/pol.1985.170230401')). So, I want to get that DOI "10.1007/978-1-4613-3575-7_2" is cited by that indicated in the input. I want to return it as a graph (It is supposed to be kinda dictionary). Thank you very much!

Comment: there are many issues, for example you are running get_citation_graph and you pass a string as argument but the function is expecting a data object (which you're not using inside the function). Looks like you would benefit from following a tutorial

Comment: Hi @Yuca, thank you for answering. But the data is returned by do_process_citation_data and it works with other functions.

Comment: in your example there is no `do_process_citation_data`, therefore I can't agree with your statement. Please improve the quality of your post by following the guidelines I shared with you on my first comment

Comment: @Yuca, I improved the quality by correcting the function name:)

Comment: it's in your best interest to provide a full [mcve] since your example consist on two function definitions that don't explain what you're actually running. In the body of the question you make a reference to my_ocan.get_citation_graph which could be understood in many ways, one of them being that my_ocan is the name of your module, but at the end of the day we can't be guessing, there is no get_citation_graph, only do_get_citation_graph. So please work on your question so we can beetter help you